# solidity assert for several not nulls

Tags: solidity

I have the following function in *solidity*:

```
function registerStudentEvaluation(string memory _firstName, string memory _lastName, string memory _subject, uint _note) public returns(Note memory) {
        bytes32 studentHash = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(_firstName, _lastName));
        bytes32 subjectHash = keccak256(abi.encode(_subject));
        address teacherAddress = msg.sender;

        assert (students[studentHash] && subjects[subjectHash] && teachers[msg.sender]);

        Note memory newNote = Note(studentHash, subjectHash, msg.sender, _note);
        bytes32 noteHash = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(studentHash, subjectHash, msg.sender, _note));
        notes[noteHash] = newNote;

        emit student_evaluated(noteHash);

        return newNote;
    }
```

And I am getting these errors:

```
TypeError: Operator & not compatible with types struct Notes.Student storage ref and struct Notes.Subject storage ref
--> notes.sol:71:17:
|
71 | assert (students[studentHash] & subjects[subjectHash] & teachers[msg.sender])

TypeError: Operator && not compatible with types struct Notes.Student storage ref and struct Notes.Teacher storage ref

TypeError: Invalid type for argument in function call. Invalid implicit conversion from struct Notes.Student storage ref to bool requested.
```

How can I assert for several not nulls in *Solidity*?

Answer (score 0):

Solidity uses two ampersands `&&` as the **logical** AND operator.

```
assert(true && true);
```

One ampersand `&` is the **bitwise** AND operator.

```
uint8 three = 3;                // 00000011
uint8 five = 5;                 // 00000101
uint8 result = three & five;    // 00000001
```

Docs: https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.12/cheatsheet.html

---

**Solution**: Use logical operators in the `assert()` condition.

```
assert (students[studentHash] && subjects[subjectHash] && teachers[msg.sender]);
```

---

Note: It's not defined in your question but I'm assuming that the `students` property is defined as `mapping(bytes32 => bool) students;`

Comment: I made the change, now I'm getting this error: `TypeError: Operator && not compatible with types struct Notes.Student storage ref and struct Notes.Subject storage ref`

Comment: Could you please tell me how does ```students``` is declared? To get a boolean value out of ```students[hash]``` I think it should be something like: 
```mapping(bytes32 => bool) public students;```.

I feel that your error has something to do with it